# MFC UDS_WRAP style not working for spin control

Tags: c++, mfc, controls

I am attempting to cause a MFC spin control to wrap its value when it goes out of its range.  The following snippet shows the code I am using.

```
DDX_Control(pDX, HourEditBox, m_hourEditBox);
DDX_Text(pDX, HourEditBox, m_hour);
DDX_Control(pDX, HourSpin, m_hourSpin);
m_hourSpin.SetRange(0, 23);
m_hourSpin.ModifyStyleEx(0, UDS_WRAP);
```

The spin control works but when I try to go beyond the range of 0 and 23, the buddy edit control does not wrap but stops at the limits.

I have also tried to use ModifyStyle instead of ModifyStyleEx to no avail.

Comment: (1) What is the return value of `ModifyStyleEx`? (2) Have you tried changing the style in the resource file? These could provide useful info for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: It should be `ModifyStyle`, not *...Ex*. Either way, it's too late to change these styles after dialog is created. You have to set these values in dialog editor (`wrap = true`), or in `m_spin.Create` if create method was used.